# Read NuSpec from NuPkg

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I have been looking around and trying to see if it's possible to read the NuSpec file from a Nuget package with VB.NET.
Essentially, I retrieve a NuGet package, but would like to get its version and ID programatically from the NuSpec before doing anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the NuSpec file for that. The ID and version are already contained in the file name, e.g. `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.7.1.nupkg`. So if you have the package file, you can read its full name and use the following regex pattern to match it with `Regex`.

```
^(?<PackageName>.*?)\.(?<PackageVersion>(?:\.?[0-9]+){3,}(?:[-.\w]+)?)\.nupkg$
```

The regex contains two named groups, one for the package name and one for the package version, so you can easily get them from the `Match` return by `Regex.Match`.

```
Dim input As String = "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.7.1.nupkg"
Dim pattern As String = "^(?<PackageName>.*?)\.(?<PackageVersion>(?:\.?[0-9]+){3,}(?:[-.\w]+)?)\.nupkg$"
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
```

As you change the name of the NuSpec file, you can alternatively load the file as XML document and extract the ID and version from it like below.

```
Dim nuSpecFilePath = "C:\Users\benjamin\Desktop\Test\Grpc.Core.nuspec"

Using file = New FileStream(nuSpecFilePath, FileMode.Open)
   Dim xmlReader = New XmlTextReader(file) With { Namespaces = False }
   Dim xmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

   xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader)

   Dim id = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("package/metadata/id").InnerText
   Dim version = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("package/metadata/version").InnerText
End Using
```

As a note, opening  a file stream and creating the XML reader by hand with `Namespaces = False` is just a way to ignore the XML namespace, that you would have to specify explicitly otherwise and it may vary in different versions of NuSpec.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I would use the file name, but the name is changed from my source, it isn't always <PackageName><Version>.nupkg

Comment: What I did in the interim is unzip each nupkg into a temp folder, read the nuspec and deleted the temporary unzipped nupkg

Comment: @user3783611 I have added an alternative that reads the NuSpec file.